# postgresql log messages in psql

Tags: postgresql, psql

I am writing some SQL code and am having trouble using RAISE.

When a message is printed (using RAISE) in PSQL I get a bunch of context info which seems to be the call chain e.g.:

```
psql:testMap:117: NOTICE:  Duplicate pt inserted {0.592268,0.796571}
CONTEXT:  SQL statement "select  insertPt(vl, chldrn[d[1]][d[2]], color) from tnodes 
                                      where tnode_id = tn_id"
PL/pgSQL function "insertpt" line 61 at SQL statement
SQL statement "select  insertPt(vl, chldrn[d[1]][d[2]], color) from tnodes 
                                      where tnode_id = tn_id"
.... more call chain
```

Is there a way to turn that info off so I just see the output of RAISE?
Thank

Comment: Maybe http://dba.stackexchange.com/ is better place to ask.

Comment: What raise statement are you using exactly? please provide a code example.

Answer (score 0):

As a superuser, you can set `log_error_verbosity(TERSE)`

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/interactive/runtime-config-logging.html#RUNTIME-CONFIG-LOGGING-WHAT